# IISサーバ上のファイルについて、ASP.NETサイト利用者からのアクセスを許可したい

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NETのWebページにファイルアップロードのコントロールが貼り付けられていて
IISサーバ上のある固定名のファイルにSaveする仕組みがあります。
また前回操作で保存されたファイルが存在する場合は事前にDeleteするコーディングも果たしています。

憶測ですがWeb.Configに
`<identity impersonate="true" userName="○○○" password="XXXXXX"/>`が記述されていることで、IISサーバ上のそれらファイルへのアクセスが許可されていたのかな？と推察を立てています。
（たしかにWebConfigでこの部分をコメントアウトしたら、アクセス拒否のエラーになった）

【質問】
この度、当該IISサーバのWindowsアカウントのパスワードが変わることになりました。
パスワードが変わる都度、WebConfigのこの部分を変更する、というのはあまり望ましくないので、他の対策があれば　ご紹介を頂けないでしょうか、よろしくお願い致します。
ASP.NET 4.0 WindowsServer2008R2です。

【フォルダへアクセス権を追加してもエラーになる】
参考①
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
参考②
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NETアプリケーションはアプリケーションプールユーザー (`IIS AppPool/(AppPool名)`)で動作しますので、アクセスしたいフォルダーに対してこのユーザー、もしくは`IIS_USERS`グループを許可しておけばユーザーを偽装せずにアクセスすることが出来ます。

もしくは偽装対象、もしくはアプリケーションプールの実行ユーザーをサーバーのログイン用ユーザーとは関係なく専用に作成し、パスワードの有効期限を指定しなければいちいちパスワードを変更する必要はなくなります。

Comment: 貴重なご見解をありがとうございます。
Web.Config上のidentityタグはコメントアウトして、
アクセス権を与えたいファイルが収まっているフォルダ=アプリケーションプールに公開された物理フォルダに
早速IIS_IUSRS（サーバ名+IIS_IUSRS）というグループを追加 ＆ フルコントロールのアクセス権を付与して、検証しました。
しかし、やはりアクセスが拒まれてしまったようです。
添付のイメージをご確認き、引き続き皆様のご見解を賜れましたら幸いです。
尚、試しに目的のフォルダにEveryOneのユーザを追加 & フルコントロールのアクセス権を付与しても、事象は変わらずでした。
よく分かっていないのですが、ドライブからアクセス権を継承させないと駄目なのでしょうか